# How to implement prepared statement in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code , I want to know Is it good and secure to do PDO prepare statement in a loop like this?:

```
 $stmt=$conn->prepare("insert into users (firstname,lastname) values (:fname,:lname)");
 $users=array(
  ['fname'=>'John','lname'=>'Doe'],
  ['fname'=>'Bernard','lname'=>'Smith']
);

for($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++){
   $stmt->bindParam(':fname',$users[$i]['fname']);
   $stmt->bindParam(':lname',$users[$i]['lname']);
   $stmt->execute();
}
echo "Succefully done! :)";
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage(),":(" ;
}
$conn=null;
```

It works properly, but I want to know Is it safe and correct approach?

Comment: yes it's safe and correct. you may add a transaction for the extra consistency and speed

Comment: and also don't do that try catch thing, it is useless

Comment: It is safe, but there are many things that can be improved, apart from what has already been mentioned. For instance: 1. not mixing array syntax `array()` and `[]`. 2. Instead of `for($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++)` and `$users[$i]['fname']` you could use `foreach ($users as $user)` and `$user['fname']`. 3. `$conn=null;` doesn't do anything at the end of your script since the connection will be released automatically.

Comment: add beginTrasaction() before forloop and commit() after for loop? @Your Common Sense

Comment: thanks. some reference site done it like ($conn=null;) https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp @KIKO Software

Comment: Yes, you can close the connection explicitly, and traditionally programmers have been trained to release resources as soon as possible. It's definitely not wrong to do so. I guess they included it to show how it is done, but you can leave it out. This is PHP, not C.

Comment: w3schools is dubbed w3fools and for a reason. this site is notorious for its misinformation